# What all is migrated when doing an export/import in SharePoint 2010?

Tags: sharepoint

I have used SharePoint's export/import tool in SharePoint 2007... Wasn't too thrilled with it. I am now having to do the same thing in SharePoint 2010. First off, just as a refresher, what all is migrated when using the export/import utility? And, is the export/import the same in SP 2010 as it was in SP 2007? If any issues have been seen with the SP2010 export/import utility, I would like to hear that as well. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my experience Powershell export/import works much better in SharePoint 2010 than the stsadm versions did in 2007. However, I also know that export/import improved considerably over the full lifetime of the 2007 product and continued to receive updates up to at least SP2, maybe further with hotfixes and cummulative updates.

I haven't found much missing after experimenting with the flags when exporting then importing a list or a library. I haven't tried the moving sites as much, but I know it is improved over the release version of SharePoint 2007.